# How to buy an app in Ubuntu Phone

Tags: software-center, timeout

Hello I have the new bq aquarius with Ubuntu Phone and I'm trying to buy the app Cut the Rope but when I try to introduce a verification code for my credit card an error popup appear and I can't buy it.
It looks like the time out is to short.

There is any solution? Or some place for report it?

Comment: What does the error say? What verification code are you trying to enter? On the add a credit card page? Is it a page provided by your credit card provider/bank?

Comment: It's just an error no number just let me try between Retry or Cancel, if I select retry it brings me to the screen for add a credit card again. Yes it's a page provided by the bank where y have 30 passwords and I have to introduce the 22 for example.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your bank's verification process unfortunately.

Comment: I think the verification withvthe bank is ok because if I buy in other websites the timeout it's one minute more or less. And in the ubuntu Phone Software Center is 5 seconds not enough time for introduce the code and send...

Comment: Have you used this process to buy something from a web site, within the browser on the phone? If the bank's page is timing out, that is all done by the bank. There is no timeout in the purchasing app itself which would cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your bank is causing this issue for some reason. You can go to https://pay.ubuntu.com/ to add a credit card, as a work around. Try this on the phone's browser first, to see if you have the same issue there. If so, it is almost certainly an issue with your bank's web site, and not Ubuntu. If that does work, please file a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pay-ui so that it can be investigated further.